# Arduino Interrupt with One Button

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, pwm, servo

I am using Arduino Uno, I try to run servo constantly from 0 to 45 degrees when the interrupt button is pressed it should go to -30 degree and wait here. When the same button is pressed again, it should resume the constant action, which is swiping 0 to 45 degrees without `<servo.h>` library.

**I tried to run like this:**

```
const int servo = 11;
const int led = 13;
const int buttonPin = 2; 

volatile int buttonState = 1; 

void setup() {

Serial.begin(57600);
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
pinMode(servo, OUTPUT);
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);

attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(buttonPin),Button,CHANGE);


}

void loop() {


  digitalWrite(led,HIGH);



for(int i=0;i<30;i++)  
    {
      digitalWrite(servo,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(1500);
      digitalWrite(servo,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(18500);
    }
  delay(2000);

  for(int i=0;i<30;i++)  
    {
      digitalWrite(servo,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(1000);
      digitalWrite(servo,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(19000);
    }
  delay(2000);

}

void Button()
{
  digitalWrite(led,LOW);
  for(int i=0;i<30;i++)  
    {
      digitalWrite(servo,HIGH);
      delayMicroseconds(1833);
      digitalWrite(servo,LOW);
      delayMicroseconds(18167);

  }

}
```

I have no problem coding my own PWM for each case but it turns out, the problem is a bit complicated than I was expecting because when we try to resume, I need to disable the interrupt function when pressing the same an interrupt button somehow.

Is it possible in this way or is there a better way to implement it?

Comment: That is a ridiculous amount of code to run in an interrupt.  Serial.print, seriously?  And, disabling the interrupt inside the interrupt handler?  Your interrupt should do nothing but set/reset a flag to be used in the main loop.  Do that and you'll likely figure it out.

Comment: Using an interrupt to read a human button press is not a good use of interrupts.  You're trying to solve the problem of blocking code.  You coded things with delay and you want them to work like a free running state machine.  Using an interrupt to read the button is not going to solve that.  You have to rewrite the code so that it doesn't use delay.  Let the loop function be the loop and use if statements and variables to decide which code gets run and when.

Comment: Why aren't you using the Servo library?

Comment: Thank you @Delta_G, I think I am going to use a switch case where counter in the interrupt function determines the cases when pressed.